# componentWillReceiveProps not firing even though state has clearly changed in the reducer

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-ios

i know there's a lot of answers to this same question on SO, however i've read through them and none seem to solve the problem i am seeing. really need someone's help on this.

scenario: we have an existing React Native app (v0.42.3) that is in the App Store and all was well. Today due to an errant 3rd party library, we needed to delete node_modules and rebuild. That has been done and no issues. The app launches fine. However now for some reason, the login flow is broken and it "seems" to be due to Redux. Its just a simple login flow. Here are hopefully all the details:

user taps login -> call action creator -> success -> call reducer -> update state which invokes mapStateToProps(state)

the problem i can't solve yet - is that :
1) mapStateToProps IS firing and you can see that the needed property (`displayLoginModal`) has changed from `true` to `false`

2) `componentWillReceiveProps` is NOT firing which breaks the app flow

**Action Creator**

```
 ..auth worked fine, then call..

 dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: { user: userInfo },
        greeting: isNewUser ? "welcome" : "hi",
        isLoggedIn: true,
        waitingForLoginCompletion: false
      });

 dispatch({ type: SHOW_LOGIN_MODAL, display: false });
```

**Reducer**

```
case SHOW_LOGIN_MODAL:
  return {
    ...state,
    displayLoginModal: action.display
  };

  case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
   return {
     ...state,
     user: action.payload,
     greeting: action.greeting,
     error: "",
     loginUserError: "",
     faceBookLoading: false,
     googleLoading: false
  };
```

**The "Receiving/Listening Component (LoginView)**

am using the @connect decorator

Here is the mapStateToProps function:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state) <== **IMPORTANT. this IS showing that the prop has changed
  const {
    email,
    password,
    error,
    ... etc...
    displayLoginModal   <== this is the prop that IS changing (from    true, to false)
  } = state.auth;

  return {
    ..snip.. other props etc...
    displayLoginModal,    <== returning it here
    isConnectedToFirebase
  };
}

....
@connect(
mapStateToProps,
{
    updateTermsOfUseAndPrivacy,
    emailChanged,
    passwordChanged,
    errorMessageChanged,
    loginUserWithEmail,
    loginUserWithFacebook,
    facebookLogin,
    googleLogin,
    loginUserWithGoogle,
    resetUserPassword,
    setTermsOfUseAndPrivacy,
    logout,
    resetPasswordComplete
  }
)
export default class LoginView extends Component {
 ... etc
```

So again - even thought mapStateToProps IS firing and displays the change in the properties value correctly - for some weird unknown reason to me `componentWillReceiveProps` is NOT firing.

Why ? This is a serious blocker for us at moment so greatly appreciate some help and advice. Hopefully its something obvious I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

alright - this is sorted. the issue here, had NOTHING to do with Redux. It was due a missing route. Not that any of the cryptic / non-existent error messages had anything to do with that. I take responsibility, but I will say I'm officially no longer a fan of React Native. death by a thousand cuts.